# How to customize my Folder View in Windows

Tags: windows, windows-xp

How do I set my Folder view such that my images and videos are in Thumbnail view while my Folders and Files are in icon view. Is there any 3d party software for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Windows XP, you can only select one of the default view types (Details, Filmstrip, Icons, List, Thumbnails, or Tiles). It is not possible to mix those types into another type. However, you can play with your icons as you want. How-to Geek has a good article about [customizing your icons in Windows XP](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows/customizing-your-icons-in-windows-xp/).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for but it will set all Explorer windows back to the thumbnail view you want.

In regedit navigate to the following key `HKCU\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell`

and then change, or create, the value for `FolderType` from whatever it is to `NotSpecified`.
Log off and back on and things should be as you wanted.

Comment: ah not this , i don't want to change all to thumbnail view

Comment: Didn't sound like this was what you wanted but was worth a shot.